# Gitlab CI variable as a regex

Tags: regex, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I feel silly asking this question, but is it possible to do something like:

```
variables:
   TAG_EXP: /some regex/

Some job:
    only:
       - $TAG_EXP
```

The above won't work, but is there a way to achieve a similar goal?

My issue is the tag is used on a lot of jobs and I'd like to have the expression in one easy to change place.

Answer (score -1):

Use [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends).

For example:

```
stages:
  - build

.build:template:
  stage: build
  only:
    - my_tag

build:one:
  extends:
    - .build:template
  script:
    - echo "my first job"

build:two:
  extends:
    - .build:template
  script:
    - echo "my second job"
```

And both `build` jobs will inherit the `stage` and `only` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's valid. The problem in my situation is the tag kicks off a host of jobs in a pipeline that are separate. So say a build job, a test job, some other jobs. So I'd like to share the regex between those separate jobs in the pipeline

Comment: You can still use extends, but just have it with `only`? If you can add an example in your question that would be useful.